# How to send response using Json object

Tags: vb.net, json

I am working on a project in which a server page is called through XMLHttp and now I want to retrieve response the called page in json object.
and I never used json so I don't have any idea about it so please tell me how I can make json object in my server side vb.net page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't too clear what you need to do, as far as I can understand you want to send to the caller JSON responses from a webserver, using VB.NET. I suggest to take a look at [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) project, which makes serializing and deserializing your .NET objects to JSON a breeze!

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.NET or use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) built in .NET 3.5.